# Printing error log message on a page in Symfony2 prod environment

Tags: php, symfony, error-log

I am currently working on a Symfony2 project and as I go through to debug I get the occasional 500 error in my dev environment, which is fine as it tells me exactly the issue.

For the prod environment, I have created several error templates so that the end user has a nicer interface when encountering errors like this, just in case I've missed something (since the dev environment is not accessible on my live server it's only the logs that help me).

However, if possible, I'd like to display part of the error log on the screen so if a client encounters a 500 error, they can recite the error to the development team. What I'm asking is, is there a way to echo a line in the error prod.log to the screen via the twig template?

Thank you
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really mentioned anywhere (except for the source code), you should be getting the full exception message using `exception.message` variable.

Comment: That does echo the error, but unfortunately it overrides the template so it's just the error on the screen which looks bad for the client. I used `{{ dump(exception.message) }}` to get this on the screen - is the possibly why?

Comment: Well, try not using `dump()` since the message is already a string. I've tested it with a 404, and got 'No route found for "GET /test"' which is fine.

Comment: Yes, that's worked fine - that's exactly what I needed!